# Google Geolocation API without Google Gears?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a possible way to use Google Geolocation API without Google Gears???

The reason being:
1. I want to user to enjoy the function of My Location without having to install installer especially when the page has potential problem of downloading the Gears installer.

1. When I was trying to install Google Gears from GOOGLE CHROME, it shows me the following error on the page of http://gears.google.com/

"Gears for Windows
Your browser is not supported.
Please check the list of supported browsers below." <---Google Chrome version 14.0.794.0 which is quite latest dated 23rd June 2011

Here is my another question, how it it is possible that Google Chrome itself couldn't support their own website??? This is ridiculous. I can even download the installer with IE 8 compared to Google Chrome version 14.0.794.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the W3C Geolocation API.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API)

Gears is being discontinued by Google in favour of HTML5 so I suspect that's why they don't automatically include it with Chrome.

Comment: rogers,

I haven't fully explored Geolocation API technologies, so, did you mean that we can actually obtain user's location without them installing any third party application?

Besides that, have you personally used the W3C Geolocation API? What I want to achieve is more to high level position such as street name, state, etc...